# How is it possible to dynamically import (or lazy load) an async component in Next.js?

Tags: asynchronous, next.js, async-await, lazy-loading, dynamic-import

Context : I have a button that pops a SideSheet component when clicked. The SideSheet is an async component that fetches user data and renders it. But I also want to dynamically import the SideSheet component, since it's a bit heavy and it doesn't initially need to show.

I tried :

//@side-sheet.tsx
`export default async function SideSheet(...)`

//@page.tsx
`const SideSheet = dynamic(() => import("@/components/side-sheet"));`

But I get this error : Argument of type '() => Promise<typeof import("c:/Users/Hatem/Documents/vscode 12-10-2021/best-in-role/src/components/side-bar")>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DynamicOptions<{}> | Loader<{}>'.

If I remove `async` from `export default async function SideSheet(...)`, then the error disappears. (But I can't remove it because I need to await user data).

What's the solution for this situation?

Comment: having the same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: @HieuNguyenTrung Nope.